# Is there a tradition that girls shouldn't be named after rivers?

Tags: name, rivers

I remember an orthodox gentleman whose son married a girl called "Narmada" and he tried unsuccessfully to get it changed.

Answer (score 3):

[Manu Smriti](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/manu/manu03.htm):

> Let him not marry..
>
> ..Nor one named after a constellation, a tree, or a **river**, nor one
>   bearing the name of a low caste, or of a mountain, nor one named after
>   a bird, a snake, or a slave, nor one whose name inspires terror.

People generally look to Lalitha-Sahasranama, or Lakshmi-Ashotra when naming girl-children, and Vishnu-Sahasranama, or related Shiva names for boys.